# ternary operator usage within v-bind class

Tags: vue.js

So I am using vuejs and trying to add a ternary operator or something that will **not** force the v-bind class to apply. Even if the data is false, it still applies the css class. how do I prevent this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cal',
  data: {

    January: 'no',
    February: 'no',
    March: 'no',
    April: 'yes',
    May: 'yes',
    June: 'yes',
    July: 'no',
    August: 'no',
    September: 'no',
    October: 'no',
    November: 'no',
    December: 'no'
  }
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: grey;
}

.January {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>


<table>
  <div id="cal">

    <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
      <th>Jul</th>
      <th>Aug</th>
      <th>Sep</th>
      <th>Oct</th>
      <th>Nov</th>
      <th>Dec</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td v-bind: class="{'January' : January == 'yes' }">askjdldsaa</td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'February' : February == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'March' : March == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'April' : April == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'May' : May == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'June' : June == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'July' : July == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'August' : August == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'September' : September == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'October' : October == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'November' : November == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'December' : December == 'yes'}"></td>

    </tr>



  </div>
</table>
```

I have updated the sample to show the issue with the conditional applied. It still renders the pink box even if I changed the data to a "no".

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cal',
  data: {

    January: 'no',
    February: 'no',
    March: 'no',
    April: 'yes',
    May: 'yes',
    June: 'yes',
    July: 'no',
    August: 'no',
    September: 'no',
    October: 'no',
    November: 'no',
    December: 'no'
  }
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: grey;
}

.January {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<table>
  <div id="cal">

    <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
      <th>Jul</th>
      <th>Aug</th>
      <th>Sep</th>
      <th>Oct</th>
      <th>Nov</th>
      <th>Dec</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td v-bind: class="{'January' : January == 'yes' }">askjdldsaa</td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'February' : February == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'March' : March == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'April' : April == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'May' : May == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'June' : June == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'July' : July == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'August' : August == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'September' : September == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'October' : October == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'November' : November == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind: class="{'December' : December == 'yes'}"></td>

    </tr>


  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have this.January in your component? Can you show your javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with the way you are building your template (and I fixed these in [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631475/38065)).

First, you can't nest a `div` inside a table like you have here:

```
<table>
    <div id="cal">
    ...
    </div>
</table>
```

Second, you can't have a space here `v-bind: class`.

Here is your code cleaned up and working.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cal',
  data: {
    January: 'no',
    February: 'no',
    March: 'no',
    April: 'yes',
    May: 'yes',
    June: 'yes',
    July: 'no',
    August: 'no',
    September: 'no',
    October: 'no',
    November: 'no',
    December: 'no'
  }
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: grey;
}

.January {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="cal">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
      <th>Jul</th>
      <th>Aug</th>
      <th>Sep</th>
      <th>Oct</th>
      <th>Nov</th>
      <th>Dec</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td v-bind:class="{'January' : January == 'yes' }">askjdldsaa</td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'February' : February == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'March' : March == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'April' : April == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'May' : May == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'June' : June == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'July' : July == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'August' : August == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'September' : September == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'October' : October == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'November' : November == 'yes'}"></td>
      <td v-bind:class="{'December' : December == 'yes'}"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Once you fix those issues, then the basic class binding

```
v-bind:class="{'January' : January == 'yes' }"
```

Is all you need to toggle the class appropriately as suggested in the answer to your question yesterday and by @LinusBorg in the answer today.

Comment: what if the data comes from an array called Array? would it be {'January': Array.January == 'yes'}

Comment: @Vzupo What is the structure of your array?

Comment: same thing, but inside of Array:[{January:'yes', February:'no', March:'no'}]

Comment: @vzupo. no looking for something super simple. Basically I can get the data with an Ajax request and when it is returned, it is a simple array. if array is called box:[{January:'yes',Feb:'no',March:'no'}]  all within... just wondering how do I access the array inside the condition

Comment: @Vzupo if you look at `monthData` in the linked example it is exactly that array.

Comment: @Vzupo here is a super basic example without using the code to generate the example data. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eKpgpP?editors=1010

Comment: what if its just one array and not inside a loop.  so exclude the v-for row in box.

Comment: @Vzupo It doesn't matter if it's just one object in an array or one hundred, you iterate over it using a loop. If it will only ever be one object, then there is no point to putting it in an array and you should reconsider your data structure.

Comment: yes- eventually it will be, but for my 1 sample its not. Just trying to see what im doing wrong and learn from my mistakes. my array was called training1.    training1.January should work for me. Thanks for other samples.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the code you provided is not a valid Javascript expression so I would doubt that it would run at all ...

This however works:

```
v-bind:class="{'January' : January == 'yes' }
```

No need for a ternary operator at all. You would only use a ternary operator if you wanted to render either one class, or another. In that case, not using an object but an array (if multiple expressions)

```
v-bind:class="['staticClass', january = 'yes' ? 'isJanuary' : 'notJanuary']"
```

Comment: please see sample above